# append title in shopping cart if size=twin

Tags: ce-1.7.0.2

Can somebody tell me the code and page to place code for this functionality?

My product titles for twin size blankets cannot indicate the size in the title. I'd like to append the title in the shopping cart ONLY if a twin size blanket is placed in the cart

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the file: `app/design/frontend/base/default/template/checkout/cart/item/default.phtml`

(replace base/default with your own package/theme)

Search for text:
`echo $this->escapeHtml($this->getProductName())`, this is where the product title is coming from in your cart. Just wrap it around the condition to check if twin size blanket is the current line item then append the size to it.

Answer (score 0):

You could add a observer which listens to the event `checkout_cart_product_add_after`

You get both, product and quote_item as data.

`array('quote_item' => $result, 'product' => $product)`

So get the size attribute from the product, if it matches, change the quote name.

Pseudocode:

```
if ($product->getData('color') === 'twin') {
    $quoteItem->setName($quoteItem->getName() . ' - extra info');
}
```